# if loop value inside function return single output and stop then why map function returning all output

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, mapping

when we loop inside function and return value it only gives one output and stop.but why map function return all output.both function gave me different output.the only difference i created is on 1st part i loop through global variable and another through argument.
this both function output is confusing me.

```
animal = "elephant"

def mapped(n):
    
    for x in animal:
        return x

map2 = list(map(mapped,animal))
print(map2)
output = ['e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']



animal = "elephant"

def mapped(n):
    for x in n:
        return x
 
map2 = list(map(mapped,animal))
print(map2)

output = ['e', 'l', 'e', 'p', 'h', 'a', 'n', 't']
```

Comment: Please properly indent your code. Use tripple back ticks instead of indenting (below the esc key ```), its easier. Its hard to tell where your functions end.

Comment: `return` exits the function without remember state (i.e. next time you call the function it starts from the beginning). Did you mean to do a generator? In that case use `yield` instead of `return`. Also what are you trying to achieve? You can just do `list('elephant')` to get your result.

Comment: i know that list function creates list but map function really confuse me on the part of eeeeeeeeee output.what exactly is map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it appears you want to learn more about [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

Map takes in a function and an iterable as its arguments, the map then applies the function to each element within the iterable, in your case it calls the function for each character within the string:

```
animal = "elephant"

def mapped(n): 
    print(f"n is {n}") # Adding this to see the output
    for x in animal: # Note you are using `animal` here, not `n`.
        return x # This always returns the first element inside of `animal`

map2 = list(map(mapped, animal))
print(map2)
```

Output for reference:

```
n is e
n is l
n is e
n is p
n is h
n is a
n is n
n is t
['e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']
```

Instead of using `n` it may be better to use `element`:

```
def mapped(element): 
    print(f"element is `{element}`") # Adding this to see the output
    return element
r = list(map(mapped, 'elephant'))
# which is equivalent to
# r = [mapped(element) for element in 'elephant']
print(r)
```

Comment: you really gave a good explanation about map function.i watched many videos on youtube but still didn't know about map.your single answer explain so well.can you tell me more about filter and reduce also?why it is called higher function?

Comment: The documentation for those functions is quite good, and includes an example using a generator expression: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter

Comment: is it good to learn django after learning python basic.i m beginner.in my opinion i thought i should really do practice by creating real project.i m currently learning both django and python.i feel insecure by practicing just iterating through variable,guessing game.it didn't let us to go anywhere.so i thought learning both django and python would teach me how to make real project..am i going right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the variables and let us think.

```py
def mapped(n):
    
    for x in "elephant":
        return x       # always "e"

map2 = list(map(mapped, "elephant"))
```

For each map, it will return the first element of the "elephant", that is "e". So, the result list is `["e", "e", ...]`

```py
def mapped(n):

    for x in n:
        return x       # return the first character of n.
 
map2 = list(map(mapped, "elephant"))
```

However, in this case, it will print the input of the iterator, so it will print `["e", "l" ... ]`

---

Your code can be written in this way.

```
animal = 'elepant'

mapped1 = lambda n: animal[0]
mapped2 = lambda n: n[0]

map1 = list(map(mapped1, animal))
map2 = list(map(mapped2, animal))

print(map1)
print(map2)

# ['e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']
# ['e', 'l', 'e', 'p', 'a', 'n', 't']
```

Comment: The `for` loop does nothing because it exits on the first iteration. Removing it and just doing the `return n[0]` gives you the same output.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Sure, That is correct and I know. My first explanation is quite bad, sorry.

Comment: If you are one-lining a function, use a lambda instead. `def`s should be multi-lined according to linting specs. Instead think `mapped1 = lambda n: n[0]`. Although I would still recommend using the built in `list` function (`list('elephant')`). Answer is better though.

Comment: Why the first part output is e,eeeeeee..why it didn't gave only e just like in our own function.

Comment: map apply the function with iterator, map(func, iter), but you give the iterator as string then it will be treated as the list of characters. So it iterate by for each character and taking a map, apply the function for each character, return the miltiple results.